# Usage difference between SSL_add0_chain_cert and SSL_add1_chain_cert?

Tags: ssl, nginx, lua, openssl, ssl-certificate

In OpenSSL [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_add0_chain_cert.html) it says:

> All these functions are implemented as macros. Those containing a 1 increment the reference count of the supplied certificate or chain so it must be freed at some point after the operation. Those containing a 0 do not increment reference counts and the supplied certificate or chain MUST NOT be freed after the operation.

But when I tried to look at examples of cases about which one should be used where I'm confused.

First **OpenSSL**:

It uses `SSL_add0_chain_cert` itself in the `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` function of `ssl_rsa.c`. [Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/52fd27f9784c9648af55b507d03d0d9e3a368855/ssl/ssl_rsa.c#L659) is the source:

```
static int use_certificate_chain_file(SSL_CTX *ctx, SSL *ssl, const char *file) {
    if (ctx)
        ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate(ctx, x);
    else
        ret = SSL_use_certificate(ssl, x);
    ......
    while ((ca = PEM_read_bio_X509(in, NULL, passwd_callback,
                                   passwd_callback_userdata))
           != NULL) {
        if (ctx)
            r = SSL_CTX_add0_chain_cert(ctx, ca);
        else
            r = SSL_add0_chain_cert(ssl, ca);
    ......
}
```

Second usage I see is **OpenResty Lua**:

It uses `SSL_add0_chain_cert` in one way of setting certificate (`ngx_http_lua_ffi_ssl_set_der_certificate`), see [here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/b87ad242dc9e50439393c5aa2d219433be9be421/src/ngx_http_lua_ssl_certby.c#L685):

```
int ngx_http_lua_ffi_ssl_set_der_certificate(ngx_http_request_t *r,
const char *data, size_t len, char **err) {
    ......
    if (SSL_use_certificate(ssl_conn, x509) == 0) {
        *err = "SSL_use_certificate() failed";
        goto failed;
    }
    ......
    while (!BIO_eof(bio)) {

        x509 = d2i_X509_bio(bio, NULL);
        if (x509 == NULL) {
            *err = "d2i_X509_bio() failed";
            goto failed;
        }

        if (SSL_add0_chain_cert(ssl_conn, x509) == 0) {
            *err = "SSL_add0_chain_cert() failed";
            goto failed;
        }
    }

    BIO_free(bio);

    *err = NULL;
    return NGX_OK;
failed:
    .......
}
```

Yet uses `SSL_add1_chain_cert` in another way (`ngx_http_lua_ffi_set_cert`), see [here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/b87ad242dc9e50439393c5aa2d219433be9be421/src/ngx_http_lua_ssl_certby.c#L1197):

```
int ngx_http_lua_ffi_set_cert(ngx_http_request_t *r,
    void *cdata, char **err) {
    ......
    if (SSL_use_certificate(ssl_conn, x509) == 0) {
        *err = "SSL_use_certificate() failed";
        goto failed;
    }

    x509 = NULL;

    /* read rest of the chain */

    for (i = 1; i < sk_X509_num(chain); i++) {

        x509 = sk_X509_value(chain, i);
        if (x509 == NULL) {
            *err = "sk_X509_value() failed";
            goto failed;
        }

        if (SSL_add1_chain_cert(ssl_conn, x509) == 0) {
            *err = "SSL_add1_chain_cert() failed";
            goto failed;
        }
    }

    *err = NULL;
    return NGX_OK; /* No free of x509 here */

failed:
......
}
```

Yet I don't see a clear difference of what changes when calling these two in **Lua**, and it doesn't seem like the cert X509, when set successfully, gets freed in either case. According to my understanding of the OpenSSL doc, I should expect `X509_free(x509)` gets called somewhere after `SSL_add1_chain_cert` called on that x509. Is that the correct understanding?

Last, the **Openssl** [implementation](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/52fd27f9784c9648af55b507d03d0d9e3a368855/ssl/ssl_cert.c#L309) of `ssl_cert_add1_chain_cert` (what boils down from `SSL_add1_chain_cert` macro) does indeed show it's just a wrapper of `ssl_cert_add0_chain_cert` with reference count incremented on the cert, but how should that be reflected in the calling process?

```
int ssl_cert_add1_chain_cert(SSL *s, SSL_CTX *ctx, X509 *x)
{
    if (!ssl_cert_add0_chain_cert(s, ctx, x))
        return 0;
    X509_up_ref(x);
    return 1;
}
```

Now **Nginx** only deals with another function `SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert` which leaves the burden of such choice behind, as it does not deal with switching cert per SSL connection basis. In my case I need to patch Nginx with this capability, switching cert per connection (but without using Lua).

So I'm not sure which one I should be using, `SSL_add0_chain_cert` or `SSL_add1_chain_cert`? And what's the freeing practice here?

Comment: perhaps offtopic, but why are you trying to switch the cert per connection?

Comment: TBH, if you don't see the cert being free'd in either case, I wouldn't be all that surprised that you just found yet another vulnerability in OpenSSL.

Comment: @cnst I'd need to switch between certificates randomly across connections, which is part of an experiment project. Now that I dig more I do realize though it might be easier to switch the whole SSL_CTX out? Because everything else in Nginx is by default set on that level on initialization...

I probably didn't make myself clear for the paragraph I said I found neither frees object, I meant to refer to the Lua OpenResty source code, not openssl. It's just up to the application to free it and I was looking at Lua module as an example :-)

Comment: Then it sounds like you may have found a vulnerability in Lua OpenResty. :-)  It's not like bugs in OpenSSL code are limited to just the openssl library itself. ;)